# Project Report with internal rate from Exact Online in Invantive SQL

Tags: exact-online, invantive-sql, invantive-control, auxil-excel-add-in

I would like to make a report in Invantive using the internal rate from Exact Online Projectmanagement. I am not able to find the right table for this report. I can't find the information which has the dates with corresponding internal rate per employee.

Comment: What tables did you check already? Is it a Exact Online configuration with Payrolling or without? (Since Exact Online has some weird options that remove fields when you have both Payrolling and PSA.)

Answer (score 2):

The internal rates with coresponding dates of activement can be found in the `EmploymentSalaries` table, see [REST documentation](https://documentation.invantive.com/2017R2/exact-online-data-model/webhelp/invantive-eol-provider-exactonlinerest-payroll-employmentsalaries.html) and [XML documentation](https://documentation.invantive.com/2017R2/exact-online-data-model/webhelp/invantive-eol-provider-exactonlinexml-xml-employmentsalaries.html).

With the following statement you will find the relevant data:

```
select EMPLOYMENTSALARIES_EMPLOYMENTCLA_EMPLOYMENTCLAS_EMPLOYMENT_EMPLOYEE_EMPLOYEEHID_ATTR
,      InternalRate
,      Startdate
,      enddate
from   ExactOnlineXML.XML.EmploymentSalaries
```